# I need u help about the homekit control

Tags: homekit

when I assignAccessory to room , after enter the accessory code, it always show connection failed,please let me know why ~And I wanna know that if we can contorl an air condition by Siri, how to do it ?It will be best regard if you can send me a simple demo ~
tks

Comment: It's very uncler what you are asking. Please see the the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page.

Comment: Concur with @Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

I will skip the first part of your question - please elucidate further before I attempt (see Alexander's helpful link).

The second question of whether you can control an 'air-conditioner' using Siri - the answer is yes, if the air-conditioner is a HomeKit enabled hardware (the air-conditioner manufacturer needs to be compliance certification from Apple). See more under 'MFi program' by Apple or the 'Hardware Developer' section [here](https://developer.apple.com/homekit/) if you want to.